# Touch Event detection issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk

when you add event listener to an object and moved outside that object `event.phase == "ended"` will not be trigger because it detected outside the object. 
my question: is there a way we can detect `event.phase == "ended"` even if the user releases the touch outside the object or is there any other way we can detect if the user has lifted their finger without using Runtime event listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following method:

```
local bg = display.newRect(0,0,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)

local rect = display.newRect(100,200,100,100)
rect:setFillColor(0)

local isRectTouched = false;
local function bgTouch_function(e)
  if(isRectTouched == true and e.phase == "ended")then
      isRectTouched = false;
      print("Started on Rect and ended outside")
  end
end
bg:addEventListener("touch",bgTouch_function)

local function rectTouch_function(e)
  if(e.phase == "began" or e.phase == "moved")then
      isRectTouched = true;
      print("began/moved .... rect")
  else
      isRectTouched = false;
      print("ended .... rect")
  end
end
rect:addEventListener("touch",rectTouch_function)
```

Keep coding..................

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the built in setfocus method which will allow you to bind a touch event to a specific display object. Which allows you to get events even if you move off the object. You can read up on this method [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/StageObject/setFocus.html) Happy coding.

```
local function bind(event)

 if event.phase=='began' then
  display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
 end

 if event.phase=='moved' or event.phase=='began' then

 elseif event.phase=='ended' then  
  display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
  -- Whatever you want to do on release here
 end
end
```